# What's the equivalent of "has_key" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

```
if dictionary.has_key('school'):
```

How would you write this in javascript?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(dictionary, key)) {
    // ...
```

You can also use [the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/in), but sometimes it gives undesirable results:

```
console.log('watch' in dictionary); // always true
```

Comment: When does it give undesirable results?

Comment: @qwertymk: Sometimes you want it to only return `true` for properties you've added on the object itself, rather than ones inherited with prototypes. The `in` operator is more like Python's `hasattr`.

Answer (score 12):

Either with the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator:

```
if('school' in dictionary) { …
```

Or probably supported in more browsers: [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```
if({}.hasOwnProperty.call(dictionary, 'school')) { …
```

Could be problematic in border cases: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

```
if(typeof(dictionary.school) !== 'undefined') { …
```

One must not use `!= undefined` as undefined is *not a keyword*:

```
if(dictionary.school != undefined) { …
```

But you can use `!= null` instead, which is true for `null`, `undefined` and absent values:

```
if(dictionary.school != null) { …
```

Answer (score 6):

The 'in' operator.

```
if ('school' in dictionary)
```

Comment: Just a note: the `in` operator works this way in Python too and many people find it preferable to the `has_key()` method.

Comment: @brandizzi, actually, has_key is deprecated so should be avoided.

Answer (score 5):

You may also try:

```
if(dictionary.hasOwnProperty('school'))
```

The `hasOwnProperty` method will only evaluate to `true` if the property is actually on the instance, and not simply inherited from the prototype -- as is the case with `in`.

For instance, evaluting `('toString' in myObject)` will be `true`, while `myObject.hasOwnProperty('toString')` will be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Or even,

```
if(dictionary.school!=undefined)
```